# ipv6 forward not work

Tags: networking, routing, ipv6

I have the following problem.

I am trying to setup an ipv6 network at my home using my server with an ipv6 tunnel as a gateway.

Here is my setup

***SERVER***:

*server interfaces:*

```
he-ipv6   Link encap:IPv6-in-IPv4  
          inet6 addr: 2001:xxx:xx:xxx::x/64 Scope:Global

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:22:3f:f0:2a:a1  
          inet addr:172.16.1.1  Bcast:172.16.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2002:c000:203::1/64  ##self assign ipv6 address for my home lan
```

ipv6 routing table:

```
ip -6 route
2001:470:6e:40f::1 dev he-ipv6  metric 1024 
2002:xxxx:xxx::/64 dev eth1  proto kernel  metric 256 
default dev he-ipv6  metric 1024
```

ping google attempt:

```
ping6 google.com
PING google.com(mil02s06-in-x00.1e100.net) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from mil02s06-in-x00.1e100.net: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=103 ms
64 bytes from mil02s06-in-x00.1e100.net: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=103 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1000ms
```

So far so good

***Client***

*client interface:*

```
en1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
ether d8:30:62:61:73:39 
inet6 2002:c000:203::3 prefixlen 64 
inet 172.16.1.134 net mask 0xffffff00 broadcast 172.16.1.255
```

ping server attempt:
    ping6 2002:c000:203::1
    PING6(56=40+8+8 bytes) 2002:c000:203::3 --> 2002:c000:203::1
    16 bytes from 2002:c000:203::1, icmp_seq=0 hlim=64 time=0.516 ms

ping google attempt:

```
ping6 google.com
PING6(56=40+8+8 bytes) 2002:c000:203::3 --> 2a00:1450:400c:c09::66

--- google.com ping6 statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

The mystery:

When I am doing a tcpdump at my server while i am pinging from my client.

```
tcpdump -i eth1 -vv ip6
23:41:03.957019 IP6 (flowlabel 0x84719, hlim 64, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 16)         2002:c000:203::3 > mil01s18-in-x01.1e100.net: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, echo request, seq 0
23:41:04.959517 IP6 (flowlabel 0x84719, hlim 64, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 16) 2002:c000:203::3 > mil01s18-in-x01.1e100.net: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, echo request, seq 1
23:41:05.957182 IP6 (flow label 0x84719, hlim 64, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 16) 2002:c000:203::3 > mil01s18-in-x01.1e100.net: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, echo request, seq 2
```

Any help?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The addresses starting with `2002:` are 6to4 addresses. Those are a special kind of IPv6 addresses and not what you got with your tunnel. You should use the addresses you got with the tunnel instead. Usually you get a routed block like a /48 with the tunnel. Use /64's from that block for your LANs.

In general unless you know what you are doing you should stay away from 6to4.

Comment: Thank you vary much for your answer. Tunnel return me a routed 64 block so i use a 68 subnet and now everything works fine.

Comment: Don't use a `/68` on a LAN. Always use a `/64` unless you really know what you are doing. If you need only one LAN then use the `/64` you have. If you need more LANs then just request a routed `/48` from your tunnel provider. IPv6 gives you more address space than you will ever need. That's how it is designed, so use it that way: `/64` on every LAN ☺